# java.io.IOException: stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: android, okhttp

Есть открытая сторонняя рабочая API.
Недавно, они сменили доменное имя (наверное, и какие-то доработки сделали).
Сменил имя, проверяю - все работает.
Но оказалось, что все работает, только если подключен Фидлер к эмулятору.
Без перехватчика трафика вылетает ошибка

```
 java.io.IOException: stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.framed.FramedStream.getResponseHeaders(FramedStream.java:146)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http2xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http2xStream.java:150)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:87)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:722)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:576)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:287)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:35)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:171)
     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: может код покажете? или по ошибке гадать нужно?

Answer (score 0):

помогает настройка в okHttpClient

```
okHttpClient.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
```

но почему это происходит и кто виноват (библиотека у меня или косяк у создателей API) - непонятно